# How can we control the segment shape in ListDensityPlot with zero InterpolationOrder?

Tags: plotting, graphics, mesh

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Abs[Sin[x y]]}, {x, -5, 5, 0.5}, {y, -5, 5, 0.5}], 1];
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> (Evaluate[
     Blend[{{-1, 0, 1}, {Blue, White, Red}}\[Transpose], #]] &)]
```

[image]

As you can see when `InterpolationOrder -> 0` each segment in the profile has a square shape, is it possible to make that arbitrary shape like a hexagon? for example, in the below plot, they manage to make it a hexagon

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We using the sampling points as below.

```
b = .1 {{-Sqrt[3], -1}, {-Sqrt[3], 1}};
pts = Tuples[Range[-10, 10], 2] . b;
Graphics[Point[pts]]
```

[image]

```
Clear[b,pts];
b = .1 {{-Sqrt[3], -1}, {-Sqrt[3], 1}};
pts = Tuples[Range[-80, 80], 2] . b;
ListDensityPlot[({x, y} |-> {x, y, Abs[Sin[x y]]}) @@@ pts, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}]
```

[image]